# Remove connecting line between first and last record of ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, line-plot

I'm struggling with a problem which should be quite easy to solve. However, I wasn't able to fix it.

Here is my data:

```
    cluster variable      value
1         1     1988  16.266506
2         2     1988   1.651491
3         3     1988   1.414906
4         4     1988   3.524106
5         5     1988   1.255048
6         6     1988   5.247590
7         1     1989  58.542374
8         2     1989  55.348154
9         3     1989   1.281950
10        4     1989  79.946518
11        5     1989 295.739329
12        6     1989 111.941471
13        1     1990  35.831376
14        2     1990 163.154334
15        3     1990   6.267801
16        4     1990  36.135324
17        5     1990  32.184136
18        6     1990  65.808952
19        1     1991 104.319331
20        2     1991 271.297555
21        3     1991   1.717811
22        4     1991   6.162088
23        5     1991 223.614068
24        6     1991 144.494680
25        1     1992  24.920946
26        2     1992  97.514737
27        3     1992   2.338454
28        4     1992   8.236198
29        5     1992 119.907743
30        6     1992  59.466458
31        1     1993  35.915740
32        2     1993  11.444630
33        3     1993   1.754765
34        4     1993   5.023139
35        5     1993   2.464351
36        6     1993  12.793560
37        1     1994  10.192094
38        2     1994  17.123972
39        3     1994   1.148919
40        4     1994  44.892803
41        5     1994  46.797657
42        6     1994  27.554103
43        1     1995  47.949046
44        2     1995  58.979519
45        3     1995   2.156014
46        4     1995   2.386940
47        5     1995  16.583813
48        6     1995  30.259352
49        1     1996  50.782284
50        2     1996  23.318913
51        3     1996 245.206559
52        4     1996  92.726616
53        5     1996  23.872951
54        6     1996  60.165873
55        1     1997  16.047945
56        2     1997  96.002264
57        3     1997 154.553556
58        4     1997   4.683534
59        5     1997   4.230310
60        6     1997  40.414528
61        1     1998   9.674630
62        2     1998 276.691314
63        3     1998   1.539398
64        4     1998  47.155072
65        5     1998 167.535475
66        6     1998 121.591620
67        1     1999   1.996771
68        2     1999  19.291985
69        3     1999   9.627251
70        4     1999   2.111284
71        5     1999   5.077251
72        6     1999   7.651787
73        1     2000   1.533511
74        2     2000   4.749388
75        3     2000  77.764969
76        4     2000   8.822520
77        5     2000   1.398238
78        6     2000   9.021997
79        1     2001   4.147357
80        2     2001   4.655750
81        3     2001   1.192090
82        4     2001   4.542792
83        5     2001   1.401844
84        6     2001   3.560301
85        1     2002   4.358921
86        2     2002   5.588824
87        3     2002   9.286483
88        4     2002   3.383068
89        5     2002   1.630102
90        6     2002   4.163573
91        1     2003 114.590967
92        2     2003 416.672354
93        3     2003   2.145251
94        4     2003   7.990705
95        5     2003 650.406070
96        6     2003 280.008212
97        1     2004  31.423147
98        2     2004  25.393737
99        3     2004   2.134556
100       4     2004  38.647510
101       5     2004  58.314884
102       6     2004  35.628008
103       1     2005 120.493931
104       2     2005  76.455433
105       3     2005 206.615430
106       4     2005  59.008307
107       5     2005  27.198275
108       6     2005  79.833828
109       1     2006 235.611236
110       2     2006  84.379053
111       3     2006  86.638692
112       4     2006 201.766197
113       5     2006   3.348146
114       6     2006 127.260565
115       1     2007  31.479617
116       2     2007   8.959114
117       3     2007   1.191066
118       4     2007  24.147700
119       5     2007  17.038608
120       6     2007  18.790166
121       1     2008  54.826089
122       2     2008   2.163957
123       3     2008   1.479409
124       4     2008   3.141238
125       5     2008   1.304543
126       6     2008  13.931403
127       1     2009  63.018339
128       2     2009 101.637635
129       3     2009   5.172660
130       4     2009  58.412126
131       5     2009 236.547752
132       6     2009 106.876749
133       1     2010  11.843006
134       2     2010   4.458760
135       3     2010  12.711000
136       4     2010  57.260891
137       5     2010  38.884449
138       6     2010  26.512278
139       1     2011 134.628759
140       2     2011 216.482243
141       3     2011   5.593466
142       4     2011   3.980969
143       5     2011  27.394367
144       6     2011  93.071463
145       1     2012   3.696990
146       2     2012  17.026470
147       3     2012  21.556694
148       4     2012   1.682511
149       5     2012  13.405246
150       6     2012   9.999758
151       1     2013   1.642975
152       2     2013  44.140334
153       3     2013  42.019019
154       4     2013   2.643122
155       5     2013   1.234858
156       6     2013  15.342229
157       1     2014   2.200339
158       2     2014   3.041888
159       3     2014  42.076690
160       4     2014   1.359859
161       5     2014   1.271090
162       6     2014   4.638317
163       1     2015  95.083916
164       2     2015 204.618897
165       3     2015   1.191329
166       4     2015  18.865633
167       5     2015 228.506156
168       6     2015 129.305328
169       1     2016  81.739401
170       2     2016  40.525547
171       3     2016 192.637080
172       4     2016   9.985224
173       5     2016  61.758033
174       6     2016  57.468834
175       1     2017 201.880418
176       2     2017  98.496414
177       3     2017 230.865579
178       4     2017  25.877045
179       5     2017  93.934230
180       6     2017 112.588227
```

I want to plot this as a line plot of `ggplot` so that every cluster gets its own line. This should be straight forward and I did this many times, but for a reason, this time `ggplot` connects the first and the last data point with an additional line. How can I remove that line?

```
ggplot(median_min_7, aes(x = variable, y = value)) +
  geom_line(mapping = aes(color = cluster), group = 1)
```

[image]

Comment: Please, [edit] your question and show the code. Perhaps, the problem can be solved using a different *geom*.

Comment: I added the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you provideds no code.. hard to check for errors.. this works for me

```
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)

# Code ------------------
ggplot(DT, aes(x = variable, y = value, group = cluster, colour = as.factor(cluster))) +
  geom_line()

# Sample data --------------
DT <- fread("row    cluster variable      value
1         1     1988  16.266506
2         2     1988   1.651491
3         3     1988   1.414906
4         4     1988   3.524106
5         5     1988   1.255048
6         6     1988   5.247590
7         1     1989  58.542374
8         2     1989  55.348154
9         3     1989   1.281950
10        4     1989  79.946518
11        5     1989 295.739329
12        6     1989 111.941471
13        1     1990  35.831376
14        2     1990 163.154334
15        3     1990   6.267801
16        4     1990  36.135324
17        5     1990  32.184136
18        6     1990  65.808952
19        1     1991 104.319331
20        2     1991 271.297555
21        3     1991   1.717811
22        4     1991   6.162088
23        5     1991 223.614068
24        6     1991 144.494680
25        1     1992  24.920946
26        2     1992  97.514737
27        3     1992   2.338454
28        4     1992   8.236198
29        5     1992 119.907743
30        6     1992  59.466458
31        1     1993  35.915740
32        2     1993  11.444630
33        3     1993   1.754765
34        4     1993   5.023139
35        5     1993   2.464351
36        6     1993  12.793560
37        1     1994  10.192094
38        2     1994  17.123972
39        3     1994   1.148919
40        4     1994  44.892803
41        5     1994  46.797657
42        6     1994  27.554103
43        1     1995  47.949046
44        2     1995  58.979519
45        3     1995   2.156014
46        4     1995   2.386940
47        5     1995  16.583813
48        6     1995  30.259352
49        1     1996  50.782284
50        2     1996  23.318913
51        3     1996 245.206559
52        4     1996  92.726616
53        5     1996  23.872951
54        6     1996  60.165873
55        1     1997  16.047945
56        2     1997  96.002264
57        3     1997 154.553556
58        4     1997   4.683534
59        5     1997   4.230310
60        6     1997  40.414528
61        1     1998   9.674630
62        2     1998 276.691314
63        3     1998   1.539398
64        4     1998  47.155072
65        5     1998 167.535475
66        6     1998 121.591620
67        1     1999   1.996771
68        2     1999  19.291985
69        3     1999   9.627251
70        4     1999   2.111284
71        5     1999   5.077251
72        6     1999   7.651787
73        1     2000   1.533511
74        2     2000   4.749388
75        3     2000  77.764969
76        4     2000   8.822520
77        5     2000   1.398238
78        6     2000   9.021997
79        1     2001   4.147357
80        2     2001   4.655750
81        3     2001   1.192090
82        4     2001   4.542792
83        5     2001   1.401844
84        6     2001   3.560301
85        1     2002   4.358921
86        2     2002   5.588824
87        3     2002   9.286483
88        4     2002   3.383068
89        5     2002   1.630102
90        6     2002   4.163573
91        1     2003 114.590967
92        2     2003 416.672354
93        3     2003   2.145251
94        4     2003   7.990705
95        5     2003 650.406070
96        6     2003 280.008212
97        1     2004  31.423147
98        2     2004  25.393737
99        3     2004   2.134556
100       4     2004  38.647510
101       5     2004  58.314884
102       6     2004  35.628008
103       1     2005 120.493931
104       2     2005  76.455433
105       3     2005 206.615430
106       4     2005  59.008307
107       5     2005  27.198275
108       6     2005  79.833828
109       1     2006 235.611236
110       2     2006  84.379053
111       3     2006  86.638692
112       4     2006 201.766197
113       5     2006   3.348146
114       6     2006 127.260565
115       1     2007  31.479617
116       2     2007   8.959114
117       3     2007   1.191066
118       4     2007  24.147700
119       5     2007  17.038608
120       6     2007  18.790166
121       1     2008  54.826089
122       2     2008   2.163957
123       3     2008   1.479409
124       4     2008   3.141238
125       5     2008   1.304543
126       6     2008  13.931403
127       1     2009  63.018339
128       2     2009 101.637635
129       3     2009   5.172660
130       4     2009  58.412126
131       5     2009 236.547752
132       6     2009 106.876749
133       1     2010  11.843006
134       2     2010   4.458760
135       3     2010  12.711000
136       4     2010  57.260891
137       5     2010  38.884449
138       6     2010  26.512278
139       1     2011 134.628759
140       2     2011 216.482243
141       3     2011   5.593466
142       4     2011   3.980969
143       5     2011  27.394367
144       6     2011  93.071463
145       1     2012   3.696990
146       2     2012  17.026470
147       3     2012  21.556694
148       4     2012   1.682511
149       5     2012  13.405246
150       6     2012   9.999758
151       1     2013   1.642975
152       2     2013  44.140334
153       3     2013  42.019019
154       4     2013   2.643122
155       5     2013   1.234858
156       6     2013  15.342229
157       1     2014   2.200339
158       2     2014   3.041888
159       3     2014  42.076690
160       4     2014   1.359859
161       5     2014   1.271090
162       6     2014   4.638317
163       1     2015  95.083916
164       2     2015 204.618897
165       3     2015   1.191329
166       4     2015  18.865633
167       5     2015 228.506156
168       6     2015 129.305328
169       1     2016  81.739401
170       2     2016  40.525547
171       3     2016 192.637080
172       4     2016   9.985224
173       5     2016  61.758033
174       6     2016  57.468834
175       1     2017 201.880418
176       2     2017  98.496414
177       3     2017 230.865579
178       4     2017  25.877045
179       5     2017  93.934230
180       6     2017 112.588227")
```

[image]

Comment: Super, thanks that works! I added my code in the question, what was my error?

Comment: `group = 1` should become `group = cluster` and your code should work (and it should be within the `aes()`. With your current code, you are drawing a continuous line (that return from end to beginning), since all measurements are in one group.